# Can you say "a lot of variety"?

Tags: nouns

I just want to know whether this sentence is correct: "method A introduces a lot of variety in the structure of X"

Comment: Yes, it's a very general quantifier of the amount of variety.

Comment: You can say "a little", "a lot", "a whole boatload" -- whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people would dislike it, but the usage is accurate since variety is quantifiable - a little or small variety would be a few different things, versus a lot of variety or a large variety which would mean many different things.

A small variety of flowers would be, perhaps: roses, daisies, sunflowers.

A lot of variety in flowers (say selection at a garden house) might be: roses, daises, sunflowers, daffodils, tulips, rhododendrons, and more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the consensus is that 'a lot of variety' is technically correct but perhaps too informal. I wonder whether it makes sense to describe a structure as having variety - isn't it the elements of the structure that would be varied? Otherwise, you might say the structure is intricate or ornate. Here's another suggestion: Method A introduces more variation to the structural components of X.